# Is it a good practice to always clone reference types in Java constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

Let's consider the following snippet

```
public class A {
    private String[] a; 
    public A(String[] a) { this.a = a; }
    @Override public void foo() { System.out.println(a[0]); }
}
```

and the following usage:

```
String[] t = {"bar", "foo"};
A x = new A(t);
x.foo(); // prints "bar"
t[0] = "foo";
x.foo(); // prints "foo"
```

although `x` was not modified at all.

Therefore, is it a good practice to always, always clone the reference types in constructors? What if the type is not cloneable?

Comment: No, it is not good practice to *always* clone reference types. If you have immutable reference types (`String` for example) it is even totally unnecessary and bad for performance.

Comment: sometimes yes, allways no. Imagine you´d like to share one instance of a class through multiple other classes. If you´d change one value in this instance you´d have to change the value for each other reference aswell

Comment: I have never used `clone()` in production code in 20 years.

Comment: @EJP I have about 10 times less time on the job, and I've never used it either. I'd say that, if you have a situation where you could have side effects from modifying an array in multiple places, your design is flawed. In a case like this, I think the variable should be wrapped in an object and only accessed through that object.

Comment: Just do it when it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not always a good practice to clone reference types as it will violate the Open-Closed Principle.  The OCP, by Bertrand Meyer, states that *software entities should be open for extension, but closed for modifications*.

Read this [article(*Do not provide a public copy constructor*)](https://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm).

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with arrays, it *is* a good practice in most cases*. The reason for that is, that the parameter array can be modified outside of the created instance by directly modifying the elements of the array. So the only way of protecting the array from being changed, is to create a clone/copy of it. Doing a clone is nothing else but overriding pass-by-reference with pass-by-value. Which way to go depends on the requirements of the implementation.

*) There may be cases, where you want to pass the array by reference (i.e. a decorator or wrapper), in that case you shouldn't clone it at all.